# How to determine whether subclass of NSManagedObject has a particular property at runtime

Tags: objective-c, properties, selector

I'm accustomed to using `doesRespondToSelector:` and `instancesRespondToSelector:` to determine at runtime whether objects have certain methods available. However, when using Core Data, I am not seeing the expected behavior for my `@dynamic` properties. For example, if I have a `sortOrder` property on my class, I can use the Objective-C runtime to see that this property exists at runtime. But if I ask the relevant `Class` object whether `instancesRespondToSelector:`, I get back `NO`. If I use the runtime to enumerate the available methods, none of my dynamic getters/setters appear in the list, which is consistent, but not what I expected.

My question, then, is: without using runtime inspection, is there an easy way to determine if an instance of an `NSManagedObject` subclass responds to getter/setter selectors that correspond to its `@dynamic` properties?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have used the following method on `NSManagedObject` objects to retrieve a list of it's properties. Maybe it will point you in the right direction....

```
- (NSMutableArray *) propertyNames: (Class) class { 
    NSMutableArray *propertyNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    unsigned int propertyCount = 0;
    objc_property_t *properties = class_copyPropertyList(class, &propertyCount);

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < propertyCount; ++i) {
        objc_property_t property = properties[i];
        const char * name = property_getName(property);
        [propertyNames addObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:name]];
    }
    free(properties);
    return [propertyNames autorelease];
}
```

Comment: I just put the finishing touches on a method that does *exactly*, line for line, what you suggest. It's terribly expensive, but it gets the job done. Thanks for affirming my approach.

Comment: @warrenm I rarely need to call it so I haven't noticed the expense. Maybe you can cache the results to disk, just make sure to clear that cache if you ever update your data model. Glad to help.

Comment: Oh, for sure. I call it very infrequently as well, and would cache as appropriate otherwise. I was just noting that it's a rather heavy-handed way to test for a single property.

Answer (score 13):

You can inspect NSManagmentObject though NSEntityDescription:

```
- (BOOL)hasPropertyWithName:(NSString *)name
{
    NSEntityDescription *desc = self.entity;
    return [desc.attributesByName objectForKey:name] != nil;
}
```